# Enhanced ecommerce for gift card

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I wish to set enhanced ecommerce for gift cards via GTM. The problem is the price is not fixed and people can insert their amount value . So, we have a box named "amount value". In similar codes that I saw, we have a fixed price. Let's say this is my code:

```
function onCheckout() {
  dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'checkout',
    'ecommerce': {
      'checkout': {
        'actionField': {'step': 1},
        'giftcards': [{
         'name': 'Giftcard1',
          'id': 'G1',
          'price': '',
          'brand': '',
          'category': '',
          'variant': 'Gray',
          'quantity': 1
       },
  ]
    }
   },
   'eventCallback': function() {
      document.location = 'giftcheckout.html';
   }
  });
 }
```

What should I insert in 'price': '' ?

Can I write

```
  var giftamount=document.getElementById('gift-amount');
```

and

```
    'price': 'giftamount'
```

Any help is really apperciated.

Comment: You cannot use a string since price is obviously a number; but you could use the first of your ideas (get the value of the textfield). You should validate the value to make sure your users actually entered a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass a numeric value here making sure that there are other charachter like currency($) and commas(,) except dots(.)
So 
var giftamount=document.getElementById('gift-amount');
'price': 'giftamount'

would become
 var giftamount=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('gift-amount')[0].textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/g,''))
 'price': giftamount

Hope this helps,